# Azure VSTS: Nesting variables to get the value of a keyvault's secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nested, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to retrieve the value of a secret inside a key vault within a release pipeline.
The tricky part comes when I want to have the name of the secret inside a variable (I want to make this pipeline reusable in the future by cloning it). So my Pipeline vars are like these:
[image: p]

I use the pipeline task to download the secrets:
[image]

So then, how do I nest variables to get the secret value? I tried several things like $($(AdminPwdSecretName)), but does not work.

I also tried to access the secret value through a powershell task, but turns out that the secrets stored by the pipeline task do not exist as environment variables, so I found no way to access them through the script. Did anyone encounter this before?

Comment: The solution so this is to use multiple keyvaults.

Answer (score 1):

At the end we gave up and hardcode the variable. The only solution I found was Daniel Mann's (to just use multiple key vaults) and is one that I cannot take in our project. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the test, we are currently cannot read the value of the variable combined with the keyvault's secret and the string in plain text.

To read the value of the variable, just set the variable to a secret variable.

[image]

[image]

In addition , you can link secrets from an Azure key vault as variables in `variable group`.

[image]